# SQL Performance Slow (Improve Insert Into Temp Table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have been working on an old auditing stored procedure that is running slowly, I have had some success from applying indexing and making the query more sargable.

However the stored procedure is still taking over one minute to complete. I think the problem lays in the temp table insert. I did try to apply an index to the temp table but this will only reduce performance as:

> The number of indexes on a table is the most dominant factor for
>   insert performance. The more indexes a table has, the slower the
>   execution becomes. The insert statement is the only operation that
>   cannot directly benefit from indexing because it has no where clause.

**SQL code**

I have posted below the snippet of code from the auditing procedure that is taking the longest time to process and included the execution plan.

```
SELECT dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail].PK_ID,
  dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail]....... 
   45-50 other columns selected from Audit Result Entry Detail 
   (Note i need to select all these)
   dbo.[Audit Register].Audit_Date,
   dbo.[Audit Register].Audit_Type,
   dbo.[Audit Register].ContextUser
 INTO #temp5

 FROM dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail]
   INNER 
    JOIN dbo.[Audit Register]
   ON dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail].FK_RegisterID = dbo.[Audit Register].PK_ID
   INNER 
    JOIN (
     SELECT MAX(Audit_Date) AS DATE,
         FK_RegisterID
       FROM dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail]
      INNER 
       JOIN dbo.[Audit Register]
      ON dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail].FK_RegisterID = dbo.[Audit Register].PK_ID
   WHERE Audit_Date >= @StartDate AND Audit_Date < DATEADD(dd,1,@EndDate)
            --WHERE ((SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Audit_Date))) >= @StartDate 
             -- AND  (SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Audit_Date))) <= @EndDate)
              AND part_number = @ParticipantNumber
      GROUP 
         BY FK_RegisterID
   ) dt
   ON dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail].FK_RegisterID = dt.FK_RegisterID
  AND dbo.[Audit Register].Audit_Date = dt.[date]
  WHERE part_number = @ParticipantNumber
```

**Execution Plan:**
[image: Execution_Plan]

I believe the bottleneck is the #temp5 table, my question is there a way I can speed up the insert into the temp table or is there a better alternative to a temp table?

Comment: please provide link to execution plan rather than as image

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Execution plan shows inserting data into temp table takes 41% of total time.  So I thought it inserts large number of rows into temp table, but looks like the final result has only 3462 rows. Can anyone explain that? Thank you

Comment: @Ryan, how many fields are you using from [Audit Register]? If you are using few fields, can you have a covering index on it?

Comment: @TheGameiswar, how can we provide a link to execution plan? (just for my information)

Comment: On the Audit Register i just use the three columns. I have implemented a covering index now on the audit register table on the audit date column. This has reduced the seek on the IDX_AuditDate index from 35.9% to 18.8%. However the insert into the temp table now takes 53% total time.  The final result returns over 15000 rows this is just a small snippet of a massive old auditing stored procedure that brings back massive amounts of data. We have set a max date selection of a month.

Comment: As to your question about a better way than using a temp table.  What is the ultimate goal for this temp table?  Is there another select on it?  Are you using the temp table as a way to break out logical steps in your process?  There are a variety of ways that might be better.  Such as using a CTE.  Could you provide entire stored procedure??

Comment: This should be on dba.stackexchange.com. @RyanGavin you probably need to configure tempdb right: several files, initial size, autogrowth option. And as a side note - avoid using full table names for referring columns, use table aliases instead: `dbo.[Audit Register].ContextUser` -> `ar.ContextUser`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess there could be few different causes of the problem.
At least, the assumption is that because of the big number of fields in one record can cause Page overflow in Temp Heap table. Along with that there might be contention in tempdb or even it's slowness. So, the general suggestions might be:
1. As already suggested, try to do not use temp table at all.
2. If possible, try to limit record size to fit into one page. Or even better, if you can fit 2-3 records into one page.
3. If it is possible, use "staging" table with clustered index on it, instead of temp table. Do not truncate that table, only do deletes.
4. If using temp table: create table before the insert with clustered index on it.
5. Fallow Paul Randal's suggestions about TempDB: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-27-of-30-troubleshooting-tempdb-contention/

For deeper troubleshooting, I'd suggest, during the execution of that query, to capture waits, locks, I/O, memory and CPU activity.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help using point 4 from your answer I have the store procedure running now in about 15 seconds. With a few more adjustments I believe i can get it running even faster.

Comment: In point 1 you suggested not using a temp table, however what would you suggest instead of a temp table? I have looked at table variables, CTE's and derived tables. However the temp table proves to be a better solution.

Comment: See #3. A "Staging" table. That is not a Silver Bullet, but in some specific cases it might help. I can't really say if it is your case or not. You know better where your contention is and you can try.

Comment: I think it should be pointed out regarding point #4 and speaking only in regard to insert slowness, having a clustered index (any index really) on the table will actually make the insert slower as it has to order it at the same time (and/or build the non-clustered ones).

Comment: That is true if you are trying to do minimally logged insert. Otherwise in case of having clustered index on a natural PK or something close to it, insert might be faster in case you do not truncate table, but do delete (see #3 in my answer). That is because during Delete SQL deletes individual records from all pages, but do not deallocate those pages as truncate does. Delete is much slower, but then insert is faster.

Comment: @SlavaMurygin, I believe it's the other way around. If you have a clustered index, then the delete function will deallocate the pages. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 "To delete rows in a heap and deallocate pages, use one of the following methods. [...] Create a clustered index on the heap before deleting the rows."

Comment: That is my own experience: Inserts into clustered index are faster after Delete then after Truncate. It might have been specific case, but you can test it.

Comment: @SlavaMurygin, I think you've missed my point. Inserting into any table with indexes is slower than without an index at all. See my original my comment. I'm not sure why it'd be faster to insert into an index that doesn't have any space allocated, but that's neither here nor there. The original point was that it would not be faster to insert data into a table with an index on it. That was my original statement and I do know it to be true from my own experience as well.

Comment: Not having indexes dramatically increases performance if you do bulk insert. Unfortunately, did not do a blog on that and do not have a proof.